# rounded edges/corners in DirectX (D3D9)

Tags: geometry, directx, rounded-corners, edges, direct3d9

I created my own little 2D-Engine with DirectX (okey, should be more like a GUI in the end) and tried to create rounded edges for a simple Rectangle. Since I never done this with a graphics framework before I had no idea how to supply this.
For now, I just overlapped 5 Rectangles and 4 circles (the circles are used for the rounded edges). It does work with opaque colors but if I add alpha into the rectangles the circles are making problems. (Shown in the image below - i should have choose another colors...)

[<# Open Image #>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JU37.png)

I can't find a solution myself (I googled and whondered I found nothing about rounded edges in DirectX) and I do believe there is a much powerful and faster method doing this. So my final question is, what are the common algorythm to create a rectangle with rounded edges in Direct3D9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to draw rounded quads is the use of textures with an alphachannel. It's very easy and the most of the gui's uses images to achieve a specific look. If you draw only single-colored boxes it may look very generic after a while (even if they have fancy rounded corners ;) ).

But if you want to draw rounded quads directly, I would suppose to generate a custom geometry, which fits the desired area directly without overlapping (need for alphablending). In you case it would be something like this:

[image: Geometry for a rounded quad]

The more triangles you're using for the corner the smoother it will look.

Comment: Well, that's the case I thought of which would be inefficient. But if its the most common method I'll join. Thank you very well ! Now I can complete my damn DX GUI :D